# Modify csv.writer code to write without blanks

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to modify the following code so that the resultant csv consists of consecutive entries of the list it's derived from, arranged vertically and separated only by line breaks?

```
with open('timeSeries.csv','w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerows((x,) for x in timeSeries)
```

This writes the list timeSeries into the csv as, for example:

3

5

6

When I'd prefer simply

3
5
6

Not sure what change exactly to make, though.

Comment: What are the values in `timeSeries`?

Comment: It looks like any other list when I print it... the first few entries look like the following: 

[8207.88, 8200.29, 8198.5, 8200.06, 8189.24, 8186.78 ...

Comment: Can you produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue? The code Timothée posted below doesn't seem to have the issue you describe.

Comment: The code Ira posted below worked... might be a Windows thing, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having this problem when using Windows...

Try adding *newline=""* as an argument to *open*. Does this help?

```
import csv

with open('timeSeries.csv','w',newline="") as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerows((x,) for x in timeSeries)
```

Answer (score 1):

if I use this code I get a csv like you want but with quote then the problem is in timeSeries ?

"3"

"5"

"6"

```
import csv
timeSeries=[3,5,6]
with open('timeSeries.csv','w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerows((x,) for x in timeSeries)
```

Comment: Yeah I wrote the same, seems like an issue with `timeSeries` to me also